# Alternating sum of digits of $π$ are bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,...$ denote by S and

$$ a_n=\lfloor10^n\pi\rfloor -\sum_{0\le i <n}10^ia_i$$
Where $π=3.1415926535...$

$S=\{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,...\}$

Define Sequence $T=(t_n)$ as
$$t_n=\sum_{0\le i \le n}(-1)^ia_i$$

$T=\{3,2,6,5,10,1,3,-3,2,-1,4,-4,5,-2,...\}$

> Question
>
> Can it be shown that,  sequence $T$ is bounded?

---

*I have no idea, how to approach this problem.Beginner in real analysis.Thank you*

Comment: This does not seem to be a problem for a beginner in real analysis !...

Comment: It is *likely* and *conjectured* (but not *known*) the $\pi$ is a "normal number". Among others, this means that digits (or here perhaps rather successive pairs of digits) behave very much like uniformly random numbers. If we take that for granted, the $t_n$ run around wildly like a random walk, and that is not bounded.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is there any method or reference for above type of function for any irrational number

Comment: @Pruthviraj $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n!}$ is transcendental and makes $t_n$ unbounded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the digit sequence $9090\ldots 90$ of length $2\ell$ occurs at some position $n$ in the expansion of $\pi$, then we find $|t_{n+2\ell}-t_n|=9\ell$. Hence if the sequence is bounded such that $|t_k|<M$ for all $k$, we conclude that such a digit sequence cannot occur with $\ell>\frac2nM$.

Decimal digits are an awful and foremost unnatural way to describe numbers and therefore relatively little is known in this area. To the best of my knowledge, so far

- we do not know of any digit sequence that does *not* occur in the expansion of $\pi$
- all digit sequences that we *do* know to occur, are known from explicitly finding that sequence

As a consequence, it appears to be unknown whether the sequence is bounded or not.
Numerically, we already find from the first 100000 digits that $M$ must be at least $1896$ (with 10000 digits, we only get $415$, and with 1000 digits, we get only to $181$); this seems consistent (of course) with the digits behaving like random numbers.